# Angular 2 Add Connect to Intuit Button

Tags: angular, quickbooks, custom-element

I am working on an angular 2 application that connects to Quickbooks and would like to include buttons provided by intuit (with some built in functionality). In standard html this would look like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ipp="">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
            content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>QBO Connect</title>

  <script type="text/javascript"     src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere-1.3.3.js">    </script>
  <script>
    intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
      grantUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/requestToken',
      datasources: {
        quickbooks : true,  // set to false if NOT using Quickbooks API
        payments : false    // set to true if using Payments API
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>
<ipp:login href= 'http://localhost:3000/login/authenticate'     type="horizontal"></ipp:login>
</body>
</html>
```

But angular 2's templates don't support script tags, and I can't figure out how to add custom tags. If someone could please let me know how to translate this into angular 2 that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it done this (ugly and disgusting) way:

1. Load Intuit's JS lib in `index.html` for your module

`<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script></head>`

2. I wasn't able to create a directive or a component with colons in the name, or a namespace — angular template parser was just removing `ipp:` from the name leaving only `connecttointuit` in the name, so in my component I had to manually append the element to DOM in ngOnInit hook:

   `@ViewChild('qbContainer') qbContainer;
   ngOnInit(): void {
       this.qbContainer.nativeElement
       .appendChild(document.createElement('ipp:connecttointuit'));
   }`

where `qbContainer` is defined in the template like:

`<div id="qb-button-container" #qbContainer></div>`

3. Then I call `window['intuit'].ipp.anywhere.init();` to get it find this element and replace with their actual button.

I hope there is a better solution ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This helped me out greatly, thank you :) Kinda sucks that angular 2 strips out parts of elements before the colon without telling you. Took me a while to figure out what was going on.